# curl get sourcecode GETparams

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the html sourcecode from that page: 
    http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar=Hamburg+Dammtor&to_spar=Leipzig+Hbf&start_datum=01.07.2012&start_time=23%3A49&end_datum=01.07.2012&end_time=23%3A51&SEA_adults=1&trainclass_spar=2

I can access the site when i go to that url. i cannot get the sourcecode via curl. not in bash "curl -iL url > site.html" nor with that php script:
i get the startpage (bahn.ltur.com).

Code for sending GET request

```
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar=Hamburg+Dammtor&to_spar=Leipzig+Hbf&start_datum=01.07.2012&start_time=23%3A49&end_datum=01.07.2012&end_time=23%3A51&SEA_adults=1&trainclass_spar=2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_exec($ch);
```

i also tried to send POST params to that specific page - but no luck.
the form is on that page:
http://bahn.ltur.com/
with [...] 
when you hit 'search' you see a short time the url above (blah/index/search/?params[...]).

any help?

///////Edit:

///////Answer:

First: get cookie from page (w/GET-params)
Second: go to the details page and send the cookie.

Thanks to @Daniel Stenberg for the hint! Give him some reputation!

```
/* get cookie */
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://bahn.ltur.com/index/search/?lang=de_DE&searchin=DE-SB-VI&trip_mode=trip_simple&from_spar=Hamburg+Dammtor&to_spar=Leipzig+Hbf&start_datum=01.07.2012&start_time=23%3A49&end_datum=01.07.2012&end_time=23%3A51&SEA_adults=1&trainclass_spar=2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
/* get page */
$ch = curl_init("http://bahn.ltur.com/details");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

without the first option, curl will simply output whatever it's fetching. And for strict "goodness", you should check the return value from curl_exec as well:

```
if ($html === false) {
   die("Curl error: " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

Comment: thank you, but still no success. no error, i still get the 'home'-page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in you cUrl code

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

The SSL_VERIFYER part means that it is not going to pay attention if it doesnt have an SSL certificate .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this happens because the page the search form is on sets cookies, so when you send the search request you're supposed to pass on the cookies there as well. The search page seems to set/update the BAHNSESSID cookie as well.

Comment: thank you! Thats what i suppose too. Lets see how i get that working.. 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "BAHNSESSID= fd12a6c3d517c702eab0014879d551ef; bla=foo");